# Getting events when adding Subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I forgot to say, this is for iOS7 iPad only.

Hi,

I have a View Controller that Build “Banner” Views in code and then adds them to a viewControllers View Hierarchy. There can be 0, 1 or 2 banners displayed at any time under program control.

I decided to use a Parent View Controller to manage the Banners and add Child View Controllers to this Parent. This all works fine as far as being displayed is concerned. It also works fine if just one “Banner” is visible at a time, however if both are being displayed then events are only sent to one of the two banners — the last one (in the View Hierarchy) that is added.

Events to the last Banner get through ok and events for the child view controller get through ok too, but not for the first “Banner” that was enabled, e.g.

e.g.

[myBanner1 enable];
[myBanner2 enable];  — only events for myBanner2 get through to the action handler.

or

[myBanner2 enable];
[myBanner1 enable];  — only events for myBanner1 get through to the action handler.

Please see a dump of the View Controller’s View Hierarchy below. I’ve also tried removing the "Banner Container View” and just adding the two banner view’s to View Controller’s .view property but the same thing happens.

Any one have an idea of what I am doing wrong?

Thanks a lot

ViewController.view - Loaded from NIB via initWithNibName: bundle
SubViews of Base View: 0xba4e130 - class: UIView Tag: 9999      Frame: 0.000000,0.000000,768.000000,1024.000000

View Loaded from NIB via initWithNibName: bundle:
SubViews of View: 0xba4e190 - class: UILabel Tag: 9999 Frame: 48.000000,26.000000,362.000000,21.000000

Banner Container View Added by Code.
SubViews of View: 0xba41f30 - class: UIView Tag: 1000 Frame: 0.000000,0.000000,1024.000000,768.000000

Banner1 - Added by Code. 
SubViews of View: 0xbb5cd70 - class: LTWBannerView Tag: 1001 Frame: 0.000000,0.000000,1024.000000,768.000000
  SubViews of View: 0xbb66d00 - class: UIView Tag: 0 Frame: 0.000000,20.000000,1024.000000,100.000000

Banner1 Item - Added By Code. An Action is added to the UIButton Object.
    SubViews of View: 0xba34820 - class: LTWBannerItemView Tag: 0 Frame: 0.000000,0.000000,1024.000000,100.000000
      SubViews of View: 0xbb80d80 - class: UIImageView Tag: 1 Frame: 0.000000,0.000000,1024.000000,100.000000
      SubViews of View: 0xbb8d020 - class: UIButton Tag: 2 Frame: 0.000000,0.000000,1024.000000,100.000000
        SubViews of View: 0xbb7c560 - class: UIButtonLabel Tag: 0 Frame: 440.000000,11.000000,144.000000,77.000000

Banner2 - Added by Code. An Action is added to the UIButton Object.
SubViews of View: 0xbb672d0 - class: LTWBannerView Tag: 1002 Frame: 0.000000,0.000000,1024.000000,768.000000
  SubViews of View: 0xbb60cb0 - class: UIView Tag: 0 Frame: 0.000000,608.000000,1024.000000,160.000000
    SubViews of View: 0xbb93910 - class: LTWBannerItemView Tag: 0 Frame: 0.000000,0.000000,256.000000,160.000000
      SubViews of View: 0xbb8df30 - class: UIImageView Tag: 1 Frame: 0.000000,0.000000,256.000000,160.000000
      SubViews of View: 0xbb8e980 - class: UIButton Tag: 2 Frame: 0.000000,0.000000,256.000000,160.000000
        SubViews of View: 0xbb8dfb0 - class: UIButtonLabel Tag: 0 Frame: 43.000000,41.000000,170.000000,77.000000

```
SubViews of View: 0xbb89870 - class: LTWBannerItemView Tag: 0 Frame: 256.000000,0.000000,256.000000,160.000000
  SubViews of View: 0xbb898e0 - class: UIImageView Tag: 1 Frame: 0.000000,0.000000,256.000000,160.000000
  SubViews of View: 0xbb92370 - class: UIButton Tag: 2 Frame: 0.000000,0.000000,256.000000,160.000000
    SubViews of View: 0xbb6c860 - class: UIButtonLabel Tag: 0 Frame: 50.000000,41.000000,156.000000,77.000000

SubViews of View: 0xbb8ff30 - class: LTWBannerItemView Tag: 0 Frame: 512.000000,0.000000,256.000000,160.000000
  SubViews of View: 0xbb8bb00 - class: UIImageView Tag: 1 Frame: 0.000000,0.000000,256.000000,160.000000
  SubViews of View: 0xbb8bbb0 - class: UIButton Tag: 2 Frame: 0.000000,0.000000,256.000000,160.000000
    SubViews of View: 0xbb8bcd0 - class: UIButtonLabel Tag: 0 Frame: 29.000000,41.000000,197.000000,77.000000

SubViews of View: 0xbb87190 - class: LTWBannerItemView Tag: 0 Frame: 768.000000,0.000000,256.000000,160.000000
  SubViews of View: 0xbb87230 - class: UIImageView Tag: 1 Frame: 0.000000,0.000000,256.000000,160.000000
  SubViews of View: 0xbb872e0 - class: UIButton Tag: 2 Frame: 0.000000,0.000000,256.000000,160.000000
    SubViews of View: 0xbb87420 - class: UIButtonLabel Tag: 0 Frame: 13.000000,41.000000,230.000000,77.000000
```

Child View Controller Loaded from NIB and added by Code using the addChildViewController method.
SubViews of View: 0xb741780 - class: UIView Tag: 7777 Frame: 0.000000,100.000000,1024.000000,508.000000
SubViews of View: 0xb738fd0 - class: UILabel Tag: 7777 Frame: 174.000000,100.000000,97.000000,21.000000
SubViews of View: 0xb7370b0 - class: UIButton Tag: 0 Frame: 212.000000,287.000000,110.000000,30.000000
  SubViews of View: 0xb745180 - class: UIButtonLabel Tag: 0 Frame: 0.000000,6.000000,110.000000,18.000000

Comment: What events are you talking about? You need to show the code for those. Are you only adding one child view controller, not one for each banner view? What are the Banner views (what class do they inherit from)?

Comment: TouchUpInside, the code that attaches it is: [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(toolBarItemButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; They inherit from UIView. There is 1 child VC, it's views are not shared. It doesn't work even if there are no Child VCs. The events work ok if only one banner is displayed, if 2, then only the last one added last gets events. It seems dependant on the order of the Parent VCs View Hierarchy.

Comment: I don't see any reason this should happen, but it's hard to tell without seeing more code. Rather than this view dump, it would be more useful to see the simplest version of your code (no child view controllers or container view) that exhibits this behavior. We need to see how you're adding the banners in code, and setting up the button methods.

Comment: It's too complex to post all the code, what bits did you want to see? And I can't post that much code here anyway. It doesn't matter if there is a child VC or not, the actions get through on one banner but not the other, and they work in isolation. Is the above View Hierarchy valid in terms on frame rects? It's looks ok to me, but if the order is changed one events stop working for the other view.